# Function not returning value from variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
IF (@crncy_code = 'JMD') BEGIN
    SELECT @total = isnull(sum(balance),0)
    FROM [PROD_EIMDW_BOJ_REPORTS].[BOJOWN].[LOANS_TAB] blt
    WHERE currency = 'JMD'
    AND chrge = 'N' -- not charged off                  
    AND dpd <= @p_days_past_upper_range
    AND dpd >= @p_days_past_lower_range                 
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [BOJOWN].[LOANS_EXCLUSION] WHERE acid = blt.acid)                          
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT acid FROM  [PROD_EIMDW_Archive].[ARCHOWN].[FINCL10_ALR]  WHERE BANK_ID= @bank_id  AND  acct_label = 'MUNDO' AND ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'  AND DELETE_FLAG='N' AND acid = blt.acid)

    SELECT @other_sum = isnull(sum(balance),0)
    FROM [PROD_EIMDW_BOJ_REPORTS].[BOJOWN].[LOANS_TAB] blt
    WHERE currency = 'JMD'
    AND chrge = 'N' -- not charged off
    AND dpd <= @p_days_past_upper_range
    AND dpd >= @p_days_past_lower_range 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT acid FROM  [PROD_EIMDW_Archive].[ARCHOWN].[FINCL10_ALR]   WHERE BANK_ID= @bank_id  and DELETE_FLAG='N' AND acct_label = 'MUNDO' AND ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' AND acid = blt.acid)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [PROD_EIMDW_BOJ_REPORTS].[BOJOWN].[LOANS_EXCLUSION] WHERE acid = blt.acid)    

    set @loanCount = @total + @other_sum
```

When I running the function its not returning the summation of the two variables its only return the value stored in the first variable. Also please note when I run the statement outside the function its okay. Below is the return statement:

```
RETURN isnull(@loanCount,0)
```

Comment: Are you running this in the context of the PROD_EIMDW_BOJ_REPORTS database?

Comment: Yes, hence Im sure that not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the problem with your query, but I would simplify it like this:

```
SELECT @loanCount = ISNULL(SUM(balance),0)
FROM [BOJOWN].[LOANS_TAB] blt
WHERE currency = 'JMD'
AND chrge = 'N' -- not charged off                  
AND dpd <= @p_days_past_upper_range
AND dpd >= @p_days_past_lower_range                 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT acid FROM [PROD_EIMDW_Archive].[ARCHOWN].[FINCL10_ALR]
    WHERE acct_label = 'MUNDO' AND ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' AND DELETE_FLAG='N'
    AND BANK_ID=@bank_id AND acid = blt.acid
)
```

Does this query return the correct result?